# Problem trying to apply dart support for a flutter project in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter

It seems not to let me enable dart support. FLutter Doctor says there's no problems. Here is a video of what's happenin: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAiGW_yOn9c&feature=youtu.be

Doctor:
[Doctor Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UV30O.png)

Comment: Please add the output of `flutter doctor -v` to your question. The Dart plugin in your IDE might be outdated.